# Netlify CMS and Enterprise Github instance

Tags: netlify-cms

Can Netlify CMS work with a private Enterprise Github instance (not github.com)? Every tutorial I've seen shows it with public Github and the configuration documentation doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

The `api_root` configuration option in the backend config section is what you're looking for:

https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/backends-overview#backend-configuration